# How much coupling is appropriate between ViewModels in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm developing a fairly simple WPF application to display an object hierarchy plus detail of the selected object, with a `UserControl` wrapping a `TreeView` in the left pane (the tree control), and another `UserControl` wrapping a `ListView`/`GridView` on the right (the details control).

The tree control uses MVVM following [this Josh Smith article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) reasonably closely, and has a number of ViewModel types all derived from the same base type, `TreeViewModel`. The main window is set up using a `MainWindowViewModel` as in [this Josh Smith article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and exposes the `TreeViewModel` used to populate the first generation of the tree control.

However, when I want to populate the details pane on the right, I have the problem that the `SelectedItem` of the tree control is derived from `TreeViewModel` when I need a completely different type of ViewModel for the details pane which will expand the object into a table of properties/values using reflection.

So, questions:

1. Is it appropriate for the `MainWindowViewModel` to expose the `TreeViewModel` for the tree control? I believe that the answer here is yes, but am open to suggestions to the contrary.
2. How should the selected item in the tree control be adapted to the right ViewModel type for the details pane? One option seems to be that the `MainWindowViewModel` tracks the selected item in the tree and does the adaption, exposing it as another property, but I'm not sure if there is a better solution.

I'm new to WPF and the MVVM pattern, so please excuse the fairly basic nature of the question. I've done a fair bit of reading around the background of the pattern, looked at some sample apps etc. but I can't quite find anything specific enough to make me confident of the answer. I also realise that MVVM may be overkill for an app this simple, but I'm using it partly as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Is it appropriate for the MainWindowViewModel to expose the
>   TreeViewModel for the tree control?

I belive yes. The model should hide the look from teh logic FOR THE LOOK, but it can not hide thigns like logical structure.

> 2.How should the selected item in the tree control be adapted to the right
>   ViewModel type for the details pane?
>   One option seems to be that the
>   MainWindowViewModel tracks the
>   selected item in the tree and does the
>   adaption, exposing it as another
>   property, but I'm not sure if there is
>   a better solution.

IMHO not.

Comment: Was hoping for some votes on answers to confirm the answers... but it appears none are forthcoming so I'll accept this given it's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the similar problem I came to the conclusion that

```
object Tag { get; set; }
```

property is inevitable :( except maybe for some rare situations (only 1 type of objects in the entire treeview).

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I want to populate the details pane on the right, I have the problem that the SelectedItem of the tree control is derived from TreeViewModel when I need a completely different type of ViewModel for the details pane which will expand the object into a table of properties/values using reflection.

If you're really, really concerned about this, you can build a higher-order view model class that exposes two different properties - one of type `TreeViewModel` and one of type `DetailsViewModel`.  Then the main window's view model will expose the same object to both the tree control and the details control, but the logical structure of the two view types will be decoupled from one another.

Logically, the selected item in the tree control and the item that's appearing in the details control are the same thing.  While the details control doesn't present information about the thing's parent/child relationships, and the tree control doesn't present information about the thing's name/value pairs, it's still the same thing.  There's probably not really any need to be too concerned over the fact that a single object representing a thing exposes a property that only one view of that thing uses.